# Extjs - Panel tools

Tags: javascript, html, css, extjs, extjs4

I have two questions:

1- I wanted to add help icon to my panel header, next to collapse icon (the default one), using:

```
 tools:[
{
    type:'help',
    tooltip: 'Get Help',
    handler: function(event, toolEl, panel){
        // show help here
    }
}],
```

but it appears like this:

[image]

How can I make put on the same bar?

---

2- On another panel, I want to add help icon next to header title, but it always placed on the right of the header. I found a way to place it on the left: http://ext4all.com/post/how-to-change-collapse-tool-position.html
but couldn't figure out how to place it in the middle, next to the title:

```
 title: '<div style="text-align:center;"/>the title</div>',
```

Comment: can you create a senchafiddle or jsfiddle with some of your code? that can help

Answer (score 0):

I think you had a mistake which is working properly. Look at the following sample.

[Panel Help Icon](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/42j)

```
var Promotions = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
        id: 'promo-panel',
        bodyPadding: 5,
        width: 800,
        height: 700,
        title: 'Real PROMO - Real Promosyon Tanımlama Sistemi',
        anchor: '100%',
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        collapsible: true,
        layout: {
            type: 'hbox',
            align: 'middle'
        },
        tools: [
            {
                type: 'help',
                tooltip: 'Hellow world!',
                    id: 'help_button'
            }
        ],
        style: {
            'box-shadow': '0 0 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.52)',
            '-webkit-box-shadow': '0 0 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.52)'
        },
        frame: true
});
```

About your second request, I have no idea but you can calculate the title width like below and set left value of the icon.

```
// this will give you panel title width
document.getElementById('promo-panel_header_hd-textEl').offsetWidth

// try this, maybe you can do this way
var hlp = Ext.getCmp('help_button');
hlp.getEl().setStyle({left: document.getElementById('promo-panel_header_hd-textEl').offsetWidth + 10});
```